# Sending and receiving packets through different sockets with SO_REUSEADDR

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, udp

As a continuation to this question: [Is it possible to send and receive packets through different sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275980/is-it-possible-to-send-and-receive-packets-through-different-sockets#20276248)

I've tried using SO_REUSEADDR (after realizing I cannot use SO_REUSEPORT).
But still, my code doesn't work.

Here it is:

```
HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=10000
recvSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
recvSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

sendSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sendSock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

sendSock.bind((HOST,PORT))
sendSock.sendto("",(HOST,PORT))

recvSock.bind((HOST,PORT))
response,addr = recvSock.recvfrom(65535)
```

I get an error on the first 'bind' line (binding sendsock).

If I omit the sendSock.bind line, I get an error on recvSock.recvfrom line.

I also get an error for omitting both setsockopt lines and bind lines, so I guess my use of setsockopt in order to bind two sockets to the same address is just not good.

Couldn't find examples on the internet on how to use them...
Any help?

P.S using python 2.7 on windows XP.

Comment: You get *what* error(s)?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting an error on the `sendSock.bind` line. Meanwhile, if you don't care what source port you use, you could always just get an arbitrary ephemeral port by using `sendto`, then call `sendSock.getsockname()` to find out what port it got and use that in binding `recvSock`. However, that isn't going to help you anyway, for multiple reasons. Let me explain in an answer.

Comment: Also, please give the _full_ platform. XPSP1 and XPSP3 both changed the behavior of raw sockets, so just saying "XP" isn't enough to go on. (Complete Python version info is also useful—e.g., "32-bit 2.7.3 from the python.org binary installer".)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this approach isn't going to work for you, but I may be wrong. I don't have an XP box to test on, and modern Windows restricts raw sockets in all kinds of ways XP didn't. But I'll give you more information to try to help explain why it isn't working, why it *probably* can't work, and what you can try.

---

But first, let me explain the *right* way to do this on Windows: [`SIO_RCVALL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309610%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Like this:

```
recvSock.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_IPLEVEL)
```

This tells Windows to deliver all IP packets destined for your machine to this socket. (A few packets destined for other machines may also be delivered, but in general they won't. If you *want* them, you need to put the NIC in promiscuous mode, with `RCVALL_ON` instead.)

Note that "all packets" means a whole lot of packets you don't care about, so you will need to filter them. In other words, instead of reading one packet, you will need to keep reading packets, checking their local address, and skipping them until you find the one you want.

Don't try to bind the socket to a particular host and port when using `SIO_RCVALL`. There are a number of problems getting this to work right, which change from version to version on Windows, and it's not worth the effort. And there's really no benefit—Windows will still deliver at least some packets meant for other ports, so you'll still need to filter them.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`winpcap`](http://www.winpcap.org) with [`winpcapy`](http://code.google.com/p/winpcapy/), which makes it easy to set up packet capturing, with whatever options you want, on whatever interfaces you want, with custom filters, and receive the packets you want without all the fuss.

---

[`scapy`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/portability.html) makes things even easier—although getting `scapy` up and running on Windows may not be as easy—try the [Windows `scapy`](http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/wiki/Home) project rather than doing it yourself.

---

Now, here's where you're going wrong.

---

I'm not sure why you've getting an error on the `sendSock.bind` call, but it may be because 10000 is outside of the ephemeral port range. On XP, that range is 1025-5000 by default. See the MSDN [`bind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs for details. But if you don't *care* what the source port is, you can always just `sendto` without a `bind`, and then use [`getsockname`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getsockname) to find out which port you ended up with, and then use that to `bind` the other socket. However, you may not be able to pick a host if you don't pick a port. (This is platform-dependent, but I'm pretty sure on Windows XP, you can only use a non-`INADDR_ANY` host and port `0` for TCP, not UDP.)

---

On Windows, if two live sockets are both bound to the same address (directly, or indirectly, e.g. via one being bound to `0.0.0.0:10000` and the other to `192.168.1.123:10000`), the kernel delivers packets to one of the two sockets arbitrarily and nondeterministically. See the MSDN article [Using `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details. Despite what those docs say, this isn't completely true for raw sockets. But, at least on some Windows versions, it's *partly* true.

---

Windows raw sockets with a protocol of `IPPROTO_RAW` won't receive anything at all. Windows only delivers packets to raw sockets if the protocol matches, so an `IPPROTO_UDP` packet won't be delivered to an `IPPROTO_RAW` socket. But that one's easy to fix—just use `IPPROTO_UDP`. See [TCP/IP Raw Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN; the Send and Receive Operations section explains how packets are delivered.

Also, you *may* need to bind the *remote* side of the raw socket if you bind the local side. You can do that by calling `connect` with the same address you used for `sendto` on the UDP socket. This wasn't required in early WinSock2, but it may be in later XP service packs (at least with default settings).

---

This also may be affected (in unpredictable ways) by whether or not the built-in Windows firewall is enabled. Turn it off to avoid that.