# Receive same packets on two sockets using SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'd like to have two sockets which, by `setsockopt()`, are set with `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_REUSEPORT`.

I'd like both of them to capture the same incoming packet for the address `x.x.x.x` and port `y`.

Any idea how to do this, without using a multicast receiver?

Comment: Unless you use packet capture or multicast, a packet will only be delivered to one socket.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to send and receive packets through different sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275980/is-it-possible-to-send-and-receive-packets-through-different-sockets)